# How to download webpage with all related content using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to download an entire webpage along with content (including the CSS, JavaScript, images, external resources) that may be required to render the webpage in any browser using PhantomJS. I do not want to execute scripts but simply parse the CSS and JavaScript for more links to contents and download them too.

I tried using tools like wget (does exactly what I need but is very slow because it uses a single tcp connection to the webserver) and httrack (downloads entire websites, in my case I want to download only contents which are required to render the page by recursively parsing links in files). I am currently trying to use phantomjs for the purpose but could not find the right way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var url = "your url goes here";
var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'index.html';//you might want to change format whether .json .txt etc.

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if(status !== 'success')
        console.log('Connection failed, page was not loaded!');
    else
        var content = page.content;
        fs.write(path, content ,'w')
        phantom.exit();
});
```

This must give you entire content of the webpage. If you need further assistance, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks Alex. The problem is, this code simply downloads the index.html file. It does not download any other content (css, js, external resources) needed to render the webpage. 

My problem is that I want to download the content once and later use any browser to render the content without facing a single HTTP 404 even if there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do it with pure **phantomJS** though! Check a framework calls **CasperJS**, that might help to achieve your goal!